# Does NAT forwards ping requests and port scans to all subnet computers?

Tags: nat, port, ping

If I ping some friend's public IP address, this is usually the address of his router.

Does the router forward the ping request to all devices on it's network?

If the devices are all turned off will you get reply?

And if you port scan such address, if 5 computers have opened the same port, can you differentiate between them all?

I just run a scan(ping scan of course) of 2032 IP addresses on my WAN subnet, and half of them were online, are these addresses of the routers of the subscribers of my ISP in the neighborhood? Many of them resolved to some uknown.ddns stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the router forward the ping request to all devices on it's
>   network?

Usually not. If not explicitly specified it will answer the ping request itself (since it is also a layer 3 device, it is able to do this). Only traffic which has been configured to be port forwarded (like TCP/80) will be forwarded to a machine on the internal network. I've never seen anyone configure ICMP/echo-request (ping) for forwarding.

> If the devices are all turned off will you get reply?

Define "the devices". If the router is off, then you won't get a reply. In the scenario above you will get a reply, even if all computers are turned off.

> And if you port scan such address, if 5 computers have opened the same
>   port, can you differentiate between them all?

You can only forward to a single IP address. From an external point of view you would only be able to see if the port is forwarded and open on a single machine.

> I just run a scan(ping scan of course) of 2032 IP addresses on my WAN
>   subnet, and half of them were online, are these addresses of the
>   routers of the subscribers of my ISP in the neighborhood?

Depending on the architecture of your ISP, yes they are the routers (or directly connected computers) of the subscribers in the neighborhood. Could also be that it's the routers of the entire state, there is no way to know other than to contact your ISP and ask for their architecture docs ;)

Comment: Thanks very much! So if the router usually doesn't forward ICMP packets, you can't capture it with Wireshark by default to notice if someone is pinging you?

Comment: I found out, at least on my router these options can be disabled and it will work:
 Ignore Ping Packet from WAN Port to Router 
 Forbid Ping Packet from LAN Port to Router

Comment: Blocking ping is completely useless. If your machine were offline, the upstream router would return an appropriate “Unreachable” reply.